# Why is my localhost turned into a percentage sign

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a remote database and the credentials are correct but I get an error and I would like to know why 'localhost' is turned into a % sign and why I am unable to connect. If I use the full remote URL of the database the same thing happens.

Here is my php page:

```
<?php
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'testuser';
$DATABASE_PASS = 'password';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'table';


$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die('<div class="error">Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "</div>");
}
if (!$con) {
  echo "<div class='error'>Not connected</div>";
}
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'testuser'@'%' to database 'table'
```

Why is localhost or the full remote address turned into %

Comment: The database doesn't have any grants for `testuser@localhost`, so it goes to the wildcard grants.

Comment: We can't see how you've set it up in the database, but as Barmar says, presumably there's no specific permission set for localhost, for that database user. Remember that mysql grants permissions on a per-user _and_ per-host basis.

Comment: Is your database really called **table** `$DATABASE_NAME = 'table';` If so thats very confusing, or maybe thats a table name and not the database name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest user record *in MySQL* that matched the username you provided was the *MySQL user* `'testuser'@'%'`. It's not that you provided that name, it's that this is the user record in MySQL. And while the password for it was apparently okay, that user has not been granted permissions for the `table` database.